# Максимально удобная отладка PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, отладка

Как можно использовать функции php через консоль?
Т.е. написать в консоли echo 123 и выведется на экран 123 без перезагрузки и т.д.
Хотелось бы, что бы объекты и массивы показывались как в консоле хрома
[image: chrome console]

Comment: xdebug, но это совсем из другой оперы

Comment: Просто до этого работал с javascript и больше времени проводил с консолью dev tools. И вот хотел бы что то похожее

Comment: "отладка" и "вывести на консоль" - это разные вещи. определитесь точно чего вы хотите и о чем точно вопрос

Comment: В PHP есть REPL: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.interactive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода отладочной информации в консоль Chrome можно использовать [php console](https://github.com/barbushin/php-console). Это очень удобный инструмент, выводит объекты и массивы в структурированном виде. Есть возможность и выполнения кода php в своей консоли. Вводить код надо в окне одноименного расширения Chrome. Результат выполнения такого кода php будет выведен в консоль браузера.

Однако отладка - это не только вывод значений переменных, а также точки остановки, пошаговое выполнение и т.д. Для полноценной отладки одним из самых мощных инструментов является [phpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). Правда, он требует установки отладчика на удаленном сервере. Так что использовать его можно только на локальной машине или VPS, но не на shared хостинге.

Также в состав phpStorm входят полноценная IDE, интеллектуальный редактор, анализаторы кода, поддержка контроля версий и еще масса других возможностей для разработчика.

Comment: Спасибо, php console классная вещь. А можно ли в ней осуществить доступ к переменным которые используются на сайте через консоль в расширении?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Надо понимать, что php работает по принципу "выстрелил и забыл". Когда php сформировал html код страницы и отдал ее в браузер, он прекращает работу и освобождает всю использованную память. Для полноценной отладки нужен phpStrom с поддержкой xdebug на сервере.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.